# Apache Server is down after PHP upgrade from PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, system-administration

I have updated the PHP from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.4. After the updated web Server apache, is down.
The Error is

> "httpd: Syntax error on line 39 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/php5.load: Cannot load modules/libphp5.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

> Line 39 on /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Include is like this "/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*.load"

> Line 1 on /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/php5.load is like this "LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so"

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

Comment: Your Apache is still trying to load PHP5. Look at the error messages

Comment: Have a look to your modules in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled et remove php5 with a2dismod ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **a2dismod** command to disable your old PHP version & **a2enmod** command to enable newer version. Later, restart apache service too load changes.

```
a2dismod php5.6  // disables php5.6
a2enmod  php7.4  // enables php7.4
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service // restart apache service
```

Comment: Ok, How can we disable this on CentOS ? These commands does not found on CentOS.